# Which car to board on train from Inverness to Glasgow via Perth?

Tags: uk, trains, bookings

Our service voucher says Reserved seats:  Coach A Seats 45 (AISLE), 45 (TABLE 46 (AISLE).  It is unclear to me what car we should board.  Any ideas?

We also have 2nd class tickets class from Glasgow to Edinburgh.  We have to print our tickets at the station.  Will these have reserved seats?  If so, again, how do we know which car to board?

Answer (score 16):

As the message gives Coach A, you can be sure that the coaches are given letters rather than numbers. So you get in at coach A, and on the platform there should be information where the coach will be on the platform, if not in text on the platform, it might well be called out when they announce the train. (In some countries you get it with your phone app details by now, not heard that in the UK yet.)
If you are not familiar with the word 'coach' for a train, it means one of the carriages or cars of the train.
The letter A, (as in other trains the number 1) is most likely to be on one end of the train. This train is likely to start where you join it and if so, it will sit on the platform longer than when it stops at other stations. Which in turn allows you more time to find your coach and seat. But do keep an eye on the time, the train will go when it is time, whether you are in or not.
As a rule there is a message on or near the door of a train with the number/letter of the coach and sometimes its destination. The numbers in most trains are in order, so you can follow from the middle of the train by looking at two doors.

In the normal trains from Glasgow to Edinburgh there are no reserved seats.
So you can enter the train in any of the second class coaches. (I do not remember whether there are first class or whatever they call them, there might not be any.) For these trains, if the train has an other class, it will be mentioned when the train is announced. Mostly as 'first class coaches will be at the head of the train'. Again, it is very likely that you will enter the train when it is waiting on the platform, at the start of its journey. Giving you more time to find your way around.

In any case, ask the people around you on the platform, in uniform if there, just other passengers if you see no uniforms. Most people do know the answers for you.

Comment: It might be useful to the OP to be explicit that car, coach and carriage are different terminology for the same basic thing, i.e. a box with train-wheels attached and seats inside. For what it's worth, most uk mainline trains are internally connected, so if you get in at the wrong place, it's not the end of the world.

Comment: @origimbo at least partially (e.g. the new bi-mode trains on GWR are two 5-carriage sets joined together and you can't go from one half to the other without a platform; I've seen this on other mainline-ish trains too.

Comment: There isn't always information on the platform about where a given coach are located (since different types of train may be used) but it will be written on the outside of the train - either in paint, a label in the window, or an electronic display. Sometimes there is a convention at a station (eg first class towards the rear) - platform displays may indicate an unusual formation (eg the train is reversed or shorter than normal).

Comment: @origimbo. To be specific, *car* is American, *carriage* is British, and *coach* is used only by railway companies themselves, not the public.

Comment: Note also that the train actually originates at Inverness, so there will be plenty of time to locate the right coach while it stands at the platform.

Comment: Coach A will either be the first or last carriage of the train!

Comment: @anomuse Never say "never". "Car" is quite popular on the London Underground as it had a lot of American influence. It's also used internally by the industry in the form of "car stop" boards. I must say though despite being prepared for it, when I visited the US I was quite confused at first when he made an announcement to passengers in "the coaches" - it took me a while to realise he meant the coach-class cars (as opposed to the sleeper cars)...

Comment: [Here](https://www.londonreconnections.com/2017/capacity-wont-increase-southeastern-metro-time-soon/) is a London (but not Underground) source which appears to consistently use "carriage(s)" when the word stands alone, but "car(s)" whenever there's a number in front of it. Make of that what you will.

Comment: Pretty sure Inverness doesn't have marker boards for where each coach will be on the platform, primarily because the trains can arrive in either direction (A can be either front or rear).